# phpinfo doesn´t list mysql/mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

The

```
<?php

phpinfo();
```

file is not showing the mysql installation when displayed on a browser,

I am using Apache 2.4 and php 5.6.4,

I have already enabled extensions

```
extension_dir="c:\php\ext"
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

I have checked that mysql.dll and mysqli.dll are inside c:\php\ext , although i have also tried moving them to windows32. No luck.

My PHPInidir points to "C:\PHP",

I have also tried moving php.ini to c:\ and changing phpinidir path. No luck.

I have edited the "path" env. variable to include c:\php and c:php\bin.

Nothing on the php installation manual helped either.

What else could i be missing?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `php.ini` should stay in your Windows directory.

Comment: Do you really need `mysqli`? PDO is often a lot easier to use for someone just getting started.

Comment: @axiac you mean it should be in c:\windows ? I also need to change the PHPInidir path, right?

Comment: @tadman Frankly, i don´t know, i just followed the steps i found somewhere. I didn´t read the mysql manual because the php manual was a waste of time.

Comment: @PabloAlgo The PHP manual is an essential reference, but it's not a very good introduction to PHP. If you're just getting started, I'd *highly* recommend a more modern approach: use of a [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) that gives you a solid foundation for building your application. Find one that suits your style and needs and follow the examples and documentation. Most have a large library of community code you can add in with little effort, avoiding the need to reinvent the wheel.